# how to fix this error "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."

Tags: c#, ado.net

How to fix this error

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

though I close my connection in this code below, tried everything to close even

```
private void cmbdealercode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtinvoiceno.Text == "")
    {
        if (txtinvoicedate.Text == "")
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_invoice where invoice_no = @no,invoice_date=@date,dealer_code=@dealercode", con);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", txtinvoiceno.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", txtinvoicedate.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dealercode", cmbdealercode.SelectedValue);

            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adpt.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Already invoice has done for the concern details");
                lblpaymentstatus.Text = "";
                lbluntilpaid.Text = "";
                lblpaymentstatus.Text = dt.Rows[0]["invoice_payment_status"].ToString();
                lbluntilpaid.Text = dt.Rows[0]["so_far_paid"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                DialogResult dialogueresult = MessageBox.Show("The entered details are seems to be new; your new invoice will be raised", "The Question", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                lblpaymentstatus.Text = "Not Paid";
                lbluntilpaid.Text = "0";
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code pasted below.

```
private void cmbdealercode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get your connection string as per your project settings
        var connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Northwind.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Northwind;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        if (txtinvoiceno.Text == "")
        {
            if (txtinvoicedate.Text == "")
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_invoice where invoice_no = @no,invoice_date=@date,dealer_code=@dealercode", con))
                    {
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", txtinvoiceno.Text);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", txtinvoicedate.Text);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dealercode", cmbdealercode.SelectedValue);
                        using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1))
                        {
                            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                            {
                                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    adpt.Fill(dt);
                                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Already invoice has done for the concern details");
                                        lblpaymentstatus.Text = "";
                                        lbluntilpaid.Text = "";
                                        lblpaymentstatus.Text = dt.Rows[0]["invoice_payment_status"].ToString();
                                        lbluntilpaid.Text = dt.Rows[0]["so_far_paid"].ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        DialogResult dialogueresult = MessageBox.Show("The entered details are seems to be new; your new invoice will be raised", "The Question", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                                        lblpaymentstatus.Text = "Not Paid";
                                        lbluntilpaid.Text = "0";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All those classes that Implement IDisposable can be enclosed inside using block and once enclosed you do not have to worry about closing the connection or disposing the object. Hope this helps.
P.S. : I could not test the code because of the unavailability of the context.

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block first:

```
try
{
   con.open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  throw ex;
}
finally
{
  con.close();
}
```